# Image with animation in iphone

Tags: iphone, image, animation

I want to use the image in view which will move like marquee as in HTML,from one end to another end of view.
Could anyone provide me with that code how to do that.

Thanks in advance n please help me out with this.

Comment: Sorry, give-me-a-code questions generally are not welcome here. You must try to do something yourself and ask about specific problems you encounter in the process...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the new Blocks API which introduced in iOs 4.0
Use this if you are not yet in 4.0

```
 CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;        
theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
theAnimation.duration=1;
theAnimation.repeatCount=2;
theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-60];
[view.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateLayer"];
```

This bit of code moves the view 60 pixels to the left then back to its original position
[please dont forget to vote if you find this answer useful :-) ]

Comment: Yes bro that was the reason i am usin iphone 3.2.1 sdk,so getting the problem.I will try it tommorow.Sure i will vote fore you but i need 15 reputations,i had 11 but somebody voted me down.

Answer (score 0):

Use uiview's transition effects..

```
[UIView AnimateWithDuration: delay: options: animations: completion: ];
```

methode.
repeat transition with some nice effects.

Comment: [UIView AnimateWithDuration:3 delay:1 options:nil animations:@"logo(1).png",@"sabby.png" completion:YES ];                                                                  I tried like this but its showing warning message.could you let me know where is the mistake.